# Kubernetes - How to change tokens for hyperkube apiserver

Tags: kubernetes

We are using hyperkube's apiserver and configuring it via a manifest file:

`"containers":[
    {
      "name": "apiserver",
      "image": "gcr.io/google_containers/hyperkube-amd64:v1.2.1",
      "command": [
              "/hyperkube",
              "apiserver",
              "--service-cluster-ip-range=192.168.0.0/23",
              "--service-node-port-range=9000-9999",
              "--bind-address=127.0.0.1",
              "--etcd-servers=http://127.0.0.1:4001",
              "--admission-control=NamespaceLifecycle,LimitRanger,SecurityContextDeny,ServiceAccount,ResourceQuota",
              "--client-ca-file=/srv/kubernetes/ca.crt",
              "--basic-auth-file=/srv/kubernetes/basic_auth.csv",
              "--min-request-timeout=300",
              "--tls-cert-file=/srv/kubernetes/server.cert",
              "--tls-private-key-file=/srv/kubernetes/server.key",
              "--token-auth-file=/srv/kubernetes/known_tokens.csv",
              "--allow-privileged=true",
              "--v=4"
      ],
      "volumeMounts": [
        {
          "name": "data",
          "mountPath": "/srv/kubernetes"
        }
      ]
    }`

I'm trying to figure out how to set up a different set of tokens than in /srv/kubernetes/known_tokens.csv to have users "superuser" and "reader", instead of admin, kubelet, and kube_proxy. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your manifest is using the exposed volume path `/srv/kubernetes`, so should be able to map that to another persistent volume (http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/volumes/) and setup the new files there.

You can do that by specifying a volume:

`"volumes": [
      {
        "name": "data",
        "hostPath": {
          "path": "/foo"
        }
      }
    ]`